# Saving file in an environment variable

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

There is a file that will be used in all of my projects under GitLab. I want to save this file contents in an environment variable (Settings > CICD > Environment Variables).
Once that is saved, I want to access this environment variable and alter the contents of this variable/file during the CI pipeline run and output it to another file on the runner server.
I can see in version 11.11, they've introduced variable type as "File" - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

I am using an older version and because of the organisational restrictions, it's not possible right now to upgrade.

Is this somehow possible on versions older than 11.11? Mine is 11.9

I've tried setting it up as a environment variable but while printing it, the build fails with the following error -
$ echo %MY_FILE_VARIABLE%
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 255

Comment: is it windows machine? perhaps it's linux and correct syntax is `echo $MY_FILE_VARIABLE`

Comment: It's a windows machine. Setting up a single word variable like MY_TEST_VARIABLE=test in GitLab settings and then printing it out/output it to a file in a similar fashion worked fine.